# How to check the production environment logs of rails application deployed on Engine Yard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production-environment, engineyard

I have deployed a rails application on "Engine Yard" recently. I am using "trail version" of "Engine Yard" for it. My problem is, after deploying the application, when I am accessing the application url, it is raising "Internal Server Error (500)". And I was unable to see the production environment logs of the application for finding the issue.

In the "Engine Yard" interface, I was able to see only "Deployment logs". And it is not displaying any error in that logs.

I have tried to access the application using "ssh" from the terminal using the command:
"ssh deploy@ec2-XXXXXXXXXXX.com"

But, it is also displaying only "deployment logs" of the application.

Can anyone please tell me that, where I can see for the production environment logs of the application. And the process or command for it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Connect the instance via ssh and seek for `/data/myapp/shared/log/production.log`

There's an entry in the documentation which may help you : http://docs.engineyard.com/find-important-log-files.html